# Can CoreData handle polymorphic subclasses?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a CoreData model (managed object) called Item:

```
@interface Item :  NSManagedObject {
  NSString * type;
}
@property (retain) NSString * type;
@end
```

I also have two subclasses of Item:

```
@interface Circle : Item
@end

@interface Square : Item
@end
```

I track the subclass of the item by the `type` property.

When I fetch my `Items`, I get back an array of Items.  But I want to be able to dynamically typecast the items according to their `type`.

Does CoreData support this natively?  If not, is there a way to dynamically typecase each `Item`?

I can get the class that I want to cast the `Item` as like:

```
Item * item = ...;
id klass = NSClassFromString(item.type);
```

I just don't know how I can cast `item` as type `klass`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes it's built in. You don't have to do it manually. You don't even have to put the `type` entry yourself.

In Objective-C there's the concept of  superclass / subclass . 
Correspondingly, in Core Data, there's the concept of parent entity / child entity. This can be specified in the model file.

In the Core Data modeler, create two entities `Circle` and `Square` by inheriting  your `Item` entity. You can specify the `parent` of the entity in the modeler. Then, in the modeler, specify the custom class `Circle` for your entity `Circle`,  the class `Square` for the entity `Square`.

Then, when you fetch the managed object from the database, the correct class is automatically assigned. 
Read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeCoreDataTools/Articles/xcdBrowserView.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006857-SW1) of the modeler.

Again, everything can be done in the modeler, without your writing anything.

Comment: Thanks!  It's frustrating not knowing what to search for.  No wonder "subclass" and "polymorphic" weren't returning results!  Just as a note, the **Core Data Programming Guide: Managed Object Models** has much more in-depth information under the sections **Entity Inheritance** and **Abstract Entities**

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer – the link is broken though, could you please update?